# In iOS do views created in InterfaceBuilder have the option setTranslateAutoResizingMasksIntoConstraints set to false?

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder

In iOS do views created in Interface Builder and later on referenced in code have the option setTranslateAutoResizingMasksIntoConstraints automatically set to false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , the option `translateAutoResizingMasksIntoConstraints` is set to false for any view created using constraints in interface builder , but the one you create in code should set it